# file input validation for images or pdf

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having 3 separate input filelds which are replaceable. I have given input field name to identify input fields, then I am calling the validation method which is to make sure that input fields does not contain duplicate files and all the three file upload fields should be either images or pdf but **can not be both**.

While this code is working as intended for the first time but then again if I try to replace the already existed files with new one then it won't work correctly.
it will stop taking further inputs.

```
   <ng-container>
            <span>
<label class="label1 " >
    <div >
    <span><img class="image1 " src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQsS20QLprBvJJNK0msxZmdu6hwqOmSiz1Mp58QLD4W0JKCSXuT" alt="img " width="30 " height="30 " /></span>
            <span style="cursor:pointer;">{{salary1}}</span>
            <span><input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)" name="salary1" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf "></span>
            </div>
            </label>
            </span>
             <br>
              <br>
            <span>

        <label class="label1">
        <img class="image2 " src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQsS20QLprBvJJNK0msxZmdu6hwqOmSiz1Mp58QLD4W0JKCSXuT " alt="img " width="30 " height="30 " />

            <span style="cursor:pointer;">{{salary2}}</span>
            <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)" name="salary2"  accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf ">
            </label>
            </span>
             <br>
              <br>
            <span>
<label class="label1 ">
        <img class="image3 " src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQsS20QLprBvJJNK0msxZmdu6hwqOmSiz1Mp58QLD4W0JKCSXuT " alt="img " width="30 " height="30 " />

            <span style="cursor:pointer;">{{salary3}}</span>
            <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)" name="salary3"  accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf ">
            </label>
            </span>
             <br>
              <br>
            <br>
            <span>
<button >Save</button>
</span>

        </ng-container>
```

//ts

```
  salary1 = "Month 1 / Combined";
     salary2 = "Month 2";
     salary3 = "Month 3";
     salary2Disable = true;
     salary3Disable = true;
     storedFiles = [];

     selectFile(event) {
         console.log(event.target.files)
         console.log(event.target.name)
         let files = [].slice.call(event.target.files);
         files.forEach((file) => {
             let found = false;
             for (let i = 0; i < this.storedFiles.length; i++) {
                 if (file.name == this.storedFiles[i].name) {
                     found = true;
                     break;
                 }
             }
             if (!found) {
                 this.storedFiles.push(file);
                 this.salaryValidation();

             }
         });
         if (event.target.name == 'salary1') {
             console.log(this.storedFiles)
             this.salary1 = this.storedFiles[0].name;
             if (this.salary1) {
                 console.log(this.salary1);
                 this.salary2Disable = false;
             }

         } else {
             console.log('nothing bro');
         }

         if (event.target.name == 'salary2') {
             this.salary2 = this.storedFiles[1].name;
             if (this.salary2) {
                 this.salary3Disable = false;
             }

         } else {
             console.log('nothing bro');
         }

         if (event.target.name == 'salary3') {
             this.salary3 = this.storedFiles[2].name;

         } else {
             console.log('nothing bro');
         }
     }

     salaryValidation() {
         const images = /(\.jpg|\.png|\.jpeg)$/i;
         for (let i = 0; i < this.storedFiles.length; i++) {
             if (this.storedFiles.every(file => /\.pdf$/i.test(file.name))) {
                 console.log("all are pdf bro ");

             } else if (this.storedFiles.every(file => images.test(file.name))) {
                 console.log("all are images bro");

             } else {
                 this.storedFiles.splice(
                     this.storedFiles.indexOf(this.storedFiles[i].name),
                     1
                 );
                 alert('You can either upload images or pdf but not both');
                 return false;
             }

         }
     }
```

[editor link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pfync2?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Javascript expert, but [this article](https://medium.com/craft-academy/javascript-variables-should-you-use-let-var-or-const-394f7645c88f) makes me think you should define the `files` variable using `let` instead of `const`.

**EDIT**

`const` actually means that once the variable is assigned it cannot be assigned again and an attempt to do so will throw an error.

`let` variables are scoped in the braces {} so the variable will go out of scope once it leaves `selectFile()`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20298210)

Comment: This is not a link-only answer. I specifically included the relevant part (use `let` instead of `const`). Could my answer use fleshing out? Sure, but it has the essential part of my answer. I shall treat your comment as "your answer may become more useful if you add more information from the article".

Comment: People really need to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/9199167). The amount of wrongly flagged and deleted answers in recent weeks has increased dramatically.

Comment: Sorry then, maybe I was wrong. I was just thinking it could be more helpful with some quotes or explanation. Here, take my upvote.

Comment: No hard feelings (once I let my nerdrage subside :p ). And you did get me to provide more useful information. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this for file type validation:

[Basic example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/file-input)

TS:

```
 selectFile(event) {
    this.fileData = event.target.files[0]
    if (this.fileData.type == 'image/jpeg' || this.fileData.type == 'application/pdf') {
    } else {
      alert("file type should be image of pdf")
    }

  }
```

Comment: actually they can not be image or pdf both @UnluckyAj

Comment: than allow only one. i mean put  validation for only one.